# cocoonjs fail to add webview plus

Tags: android, installation, cocoonjs

I have a problem setting up cocoon according to their manual at:
http://support.ludei.com/hc/en-us/articles/202568973-First-steps-with-CocoonJS-CLI

When I try to do:

```
cocoonjs plugin add com.ludei.webview.plus
```

I get the error:

```
[CocoonJS] Executing command 'plugin add com.ludei.webview.plus'
[CocoonJS] Installing Webview+ in your Cordova Project.
[CocoonJS] The command `android` failed. Add the platform-tools/ as well as the tools/ directory to your PATH environment variable.
```

But I already have those in my path:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/gerard/adt-bundle-linux-x8664-20140702/sdk
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/gerard/gcc-arm-none-eabi-48-2014q3/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

This configuration is working with phonegap, I am trying switch to cocoonjs now but this seems to go wrong.

Can anyone tell me what can be wrong else than the PATH problem?

Comment: ANDROIDHOME vs ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: Apologies, that is typing error from me, I should have just copied it. It is correct in my path, I updated my post.